# SQL Geometry incorrectly throws invalid geometry errors if query is larger than ~200,000 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry

I'm trying to determine the distribution of geometry types in a large geometry table, but keep getting an invalid geometry error even after using the STIsValid() function.

The code I'm using is:

```
WITH validDimensions AS
(
SELECT [id], [geometry]
FROM dimensions
WHERE [geometry].STIsValid()=1
)

SELECT COUNT(id), [geometry].STGeometryType() AS [GeometryType]
FROM validDimensions
GROUP BY
[geometry].STGeometryType()
```

If I filter the first query to any range less than ~200,000 rows the query works fine.

For example,

This query works:

`WHERE [geometry].STIsValid()=1 AND id <200000`

and this query works:

`WHERE [geometry].STIsValid()=1 AND id > 150000 AND id <300000`

but this query fails:

`WHERE [geometry].STIsValid()=1 AND id <250000`

The error is:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 A .NET Framework error occurred
>   during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
>   System.ArgumentException: 24144: This operation cannot be completed
>   because the instance is not valid. Use MakeValid to convert the
>   instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points
>   of a geometry instance to shift slightly. System.ArgumentException: 
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.ThrowIfInvalid()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.STGeometryType()

I can get the query to run by using .MakeValid() but it is too slow to be usable. Has anyone come across this?

EDIT:
I've got this to work by switching to a temp table instead of using 'WITH':

```
SELECT [id], [geometry]
INTO validdimensions
FROM dimensions
WHERE [geometry].STIsValid()=1


SELECT COUNT(id), [geometry].STGeometryType() AS [GeometryType]
FROM validDimensions
GROUP BY
[geometry].STGeometryType()
```

I'm still interested to know why the first query is getting errors.

Thanks,

Max

Comment: Do you have an example geometry where IsValid() = 1 but isn't valid?

Comment: Hi, I must have an example somewhere in the table, but how can I tell which one out of ~5 million is causing the error? Can I identify error rows using T-SQL transactions or something?

Comment: That is a bit of a chicken and egg problem, eh? Failing better methods, do a binary search. That is, assuming your table has something like an identity column, try the above query with an additional predicate of `and ID > «halfway point of your id range»` and see if it breaks. If it does, you know you've got an invalid geometry in that range. Keep bisecting the range until you arrive at one row.

Comment: Haha alright I'll be back in seven and a half million years, although will first check that the answer is not 42.

Seriously though thanks, I'll see if I can narrow it down.

Comment: I did the math and the it should be log2(5 million) ≈ 23. So unless each query takes ≈ 320000 years, I think you'll be done sooner than that. Logarithms ftw! ;)

Comment: Ok this is starting to feel buggy. It doesn't matter which range of Id's I use, but if the range is wider than ~200,000 rows then it throws the error. Editing the question to reflect this.

Comment: That's… weird. This just occurred to me now, but can you push the `STGeometryType()` into the cte? Or does that bomb as well?

Comment: No I can't put the STGeometryType() in the initial query because there are 30,000 invalid geometries in the table and for this query I just want to ignore them, hence removing them first with the CTE. Added a new edit - I've got it to work with a temp table but still don't understand the CTE behaviour.

Comment: My only thought would be to look at the query plan and see what private is being applied where. In the case where you're hitting a tipping point, it might be doing a table scan and applying the STIsValid check late in the plan.